# Automatic differentiation using expression templates c++

Tags: c++, crtp, automatic-differentiation, expression-templates

## Introduction

I am trying to learn about expression templates because it seems to be a very powerful technique for a wide range of calculations. I looked at different examples online (e.g. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates)), and I wrote a bunch of small programs that do different calculations. However, I found a problem that I can't solve; namely, the assignment of an arbitrary expression to a variable, its "lazy evaluation", and its re-assignment to another arbitrary expression.

One can use `auto`, in order to assign an expression to a variable, but reassignment to another expression is impossible (you can have a look at the entire library [sadET](https://github.com/dkaramit/sadET/tree/simplificationRules), in order to fully understand what I am trying to do). Also, the assignment and reassignment  can be done using [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), and overloading `operator=`. However, the expression is evaluated during the assignment, and we basically lose all information on what the expression is.

Therefore, I tried to use Polymorphic cloning + CRTP (e.g. see [this](https://katyscode.wordpress.com/2013/08/22/c-polymorphic-cloning-and-the-crtp-curiously-recurring-template-pattern/)), which kind of works, but I get a segfault when I try to reassign the variable to an expression that contains the same variable.

## Code

In the code below, I show a simplified version of how I implement the addition expression template. In the code that follows, `msg` is a macro for `std::cout<<typeid(*this).name()<<std::endl;`, in order to keep track of what is being evaluated.

This is the (pure) base class of all expressions, which will allow me to assign a variable to a generic expression (using polymorphic cloning):

```cpp
struct BaseExpression{
    BaseExpression()=default;
    virtual double evaluate()const =0 ;
};
```

This is a class from which all expressions inherit, and  will allow me to use CRTP

```cpp
template<typename subExpr>
struct GenericExpression:BaseExpression{
    const subExpr& self() const {return static_cast<const subExpr&>(*this);}
    subExpr& self() {return static_cast<subExpr&>(*this);}    
    double evaluate() const { msg; return self().evaluate(); };
};
```

The idea is that all expressions are made of numbers, elementary functions, and operators. So, I write a `Number` class as follows

```cpp
class Number: public GenericExpression<Number>{
    double val;
    public:
    Number()=default;

    Number(const double &x):val(x){}
    Number(const Number &x):val(x.evaluate()){}
    
    double evaluate()const  { msg; return val;}
    double& evaluate() { msg; return val;}
};
```

Following the ideas of expression templates, then, the addition is

```cpp
template<typename leftHand,typename rightHand>
class Addition:public GenericExpression<Addition<leftHand,rightHand>>{
    const leftHand &LH;
    const rightHand &RH;

    public:
    Addition(const leftHand &LH, const rightHand &RH):LH(LH),RH(RH){}

    double evaluate() const {msg; return LH.evaluate() + RH.evaluate();}
};

template<typename leftHand,typename rightHand>
Addition<leftHand,rightHand> 
operator+(const GenericExpression<leftHand> &LH, const GenericExpression<rightHand> &RH){
    return Addition<leftHand,rightHand>(LH.self(),RH.self()); 
}
```

In order to be able to utilize `BaseExpression`, I also write an `Expression` class that will be used to assign instances of `GenericExpression` to  `Expression` variables.

```cpp
class Expression: public GenericExpression<Expression>{
    public:
    BaseExpression *baseExpr;

    Expression()=default;
    Expression(const Expression &E){baseExpr = E.baseExpr;};

    double evaluate() const {msg;  return baseExpr->evaluate();}
    
    template<typename subExpr>
    void assign(const GenericExpression<subExpr> &RH){        
        baseExpr = new subExpr(RH.self());
    }

};
```

I this class, the important bit is the pointer `baseExpr` that allows to change the `evaluate` function to the `GenericExpression` when we call assign.

### Some examples

In order to test whether this worked, I declare the following variables:

```cpp
    Number x(3.2);
    Number y(-2.3);
    Expression z,w;
```

Then, we can see that the following things work

```cpp
    //assignment to Number
    z.assign(x);
    cout<<z.evaluate()<<endl;


    //assignment to Addition<Number,Number>
    z.assign(x+y);
    cout<<z.evaluate()<<endl;

    
    //assignment to Addition<Expression,Number>
    w.assign(z+y);
    cout<<w.evaluate()<<endl;
```

However, when I do the following, I get an infinite recursion when I run `z.evaluate()` since `z.baseExpr` points to itself.

```cpp
    // Segmentation fault of z.evaluate() due to infinite recursion between
    // LH.evaluate() (in Addition<Expression,Number>::evaluate()) and 
    // baseExpr->evaluate() (in Expression::evaluate())
    z.assign(z+x);
    cout<<z.evaluate()<<endl;
```

### The entire code that reproduces the behavior I describe:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>


// message to print during evaluation, in order to track the evaluation path.
#define msg std::cout<<typeid(*this).name()<<std::endl;


struct BaseExpression{
    BaseExpression()=default;
    virtual double evaluate()const =0 ;
};

template<typename subExpr>
struct GenericExpression:BaseExpression{
    const subExpr& self() const {return static_cast<const subExpr&>(*this);}
    subExpr& self() {return static_cast<subExpr&>(*this);}
    
    double evaluate() const { msg; return self().evaluate(); };
};


class Number: public GenericExpression<Number>{
    double val;
    public:
    Number()=default;

    Number(const double &x):val(x){}
    Number(const Number &x):val(x.evaluate()){}
    
    double evaluate()const  { msg; return val;}
    double& evaluate() { msg; return val;}
};

template<typename leftHand,typename rightHand>
class Addition:public GenericExpression<Addition<leftHand,rightHand>>{
    const leftHand &LH;
    const rightHand &RH;

    public:
    Addition(const leftHand &LH, const rightHand &RH):LH(LH),RH(RH){}

    double evaluate() const {msg; return LH.evaluate() + RH.evaluate();}
};

template<typename leftHand,typename rightHand>
Addition<leftHand,rightHand> 
operator+(const GenericExpression<leftHand> &LH, const GenericExpression<rightHand> &RH){
    return Addition<leftHand,rightHand>(LH.self(),RH.self()); 
}


class Expression: public GenericExpression<Expression>{
    public:
    BaseExpression *baseExpr;

    Expression()=default;
    Expression(const Expression &E){baseExpr = E.baseExpr;};
    // Expression(Expression *E){baseExpr = E->baseExpr;};

    double evaluate() const {msg;  return baseExpr->evaluate();}


    template<typename subExpr>
    void assign(const GenericExpression<subExpr> &RH){
        
        baseExpr = new subExpr(RH.self());
    }

};


using std::cout;
using std::endl;


int main(){
    Number x(3.2);
    Number y(-2.3);
    Expression z,w;

    // works fine!
    z.assign(x);
    cout<<z.evaluate()<<endl;
    // works fine!
    z.assign(x+y);
    cout<<z.evaluate()<<endl;

    
    // works fine!
    w.assign(z+y);
    cout<<w.evaluate()<<endl;

    // Segmentation fault of z.evaluate() infinite recursion in between
    // LH.evaluate() (in Addition<Expression,Number>::evaluate()) and 
    // baseExpr->evaluate() (in Expression::evaluate())
    z.assign(z+x);
    cout<<z.evaluate()<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

## Moving to autodiff

Implementation of automatic differentiation is not that different than the example above. The most important changes are the introduction of a `Constant` class and a `derivative` member function to all classes derived from `GenericExpression`, that returns an arbitrary expression. That is, we add

```cpp
class Constant: public GenericExpression<Constant>{
    double val;
    public:
    Constant()=default;

    Constant(const double &x):val(x){}
    Constant(const Constant &x):val(x.evaluate()){}
    
    double evaluate()const  { msg; return val;}
    double& evaluate() { msg; return val;}
    
    auto derivative(){return Constant(0);}
};
```

The `derivative` member in the other classes should look like:

```cpp
auto Number::derivative(){return Constant(1);}

template<typename leftHand,typename rightHand>
auto Addition<left,right>::derivative(){return LH.derivative() + RH.derivative();}
```

### The problem

Even if we find a way to avoid (or ignore) the segfault I showed previously, I see  no way that I can make `derivative`  a virtual member funtion of `BaseExpression`, since it returns a different kind of expression that, in principle, we only know when we call it (hence the `auto`).

## Final question

In the context I tried to describe, is there any way I can do the following

```cpp
    Number x(5);
    Expression z;
    
    z.assign(x);
    z.assign(z+x);
    
    cout<<z.evaluate()<<endl;
    cout<<z.derivative().evaluate()<<endl;
```

preferably without segfault?

I would appreciate the input or insight of the community!

## Edit

I simplified the code in order to makes things a bit easier, and avoid potential dangerous pointers.

In this example, I made the member function `evaluate` a function pointer to lambdas. This way, and if I understand correctly, I copy directly the `...::evaluate` to `Expression::evaluate`. However, I still get Segfaults...

Curiously, I get Segfault when using a recursive function to sum over vector.

### New code:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<functional>
#include<vector>


// message to print during evaluation, in order to track the evaluation path.
#define msg std::cout<<typeid(*this).name()<<std::endl


class Expression{
    public:
    std::function<double(void)> evaluate;
    
    template<typename T>
    Expression(const T &RH){evaluate = RH.evaluate;}

    template<typename T>
    Expression& operator=(const T &RH){evaluate = RH.evaluate; return *this;}
};




class Number{ 
    double val;
    public:
    Number()=default;

    std::function<double()> evaluate;

    Number(const double &x):val(x){ evaluate = [this](){msg; return this->val;};  }
    Number(const Number &x):val(x.evaluate()){ evaluate = [this](){msg; return this->val;}; }
};

template<typename leftHand,typename rightHand>
class Addition{ 
    const leftHand &LH;
    const rightHand &RH;

    public:
    std::function<double()> evaluate;

    Addition(const leftHand &LH, const rightHand &RH):LH(LH),RH(RH)
    {evaluate = [this](){msg; return this->LH.evaluate() + this->RH.evaluate();};}
};

template<typename leftHand,typename rightHand>
auto operator+(const leftHand &LH, const rightHand &RH){return Addition<leftHand,rightHand>(LH,RH); }



using std::cout;
using std::endl;


inline Expression func (std::vector<Expression> x, int i){
    cout<<i<<endl;

    if (i==0){return static_cast<Expression>(x[0]);}    

    return static_cast<Expression>( x[i] + func(x,i-1) ) ;
};


int main(){
    Number y(-2.);
    Number x(1.33);

    Expression z(y+x);
    Expression w(x+y+x);
    
    // works
    z =x;
    cout<<z.evaluate()<<endl;
    cout<<(z+z+z+z).evaluate()<<endl;

    // Segfault due to recusion 
    // z =z+x;
    // cout<<z.evaluate()<<endl;

    // Unkown Segfault 
    // z = x+y ;
    // cout<<(z+z).evaluate()<<endl;
    // cout<<typeid(z+z).name()<<endl;

    // Unkown Segfault 
    // z = w+y+x+x;
    // cout<<z.evaluate()<<endl;

    
    
    // Unkown Segfault 
    // std::vector<Expression> X={x,y,x,y,x,y,x,y};

    // cout << typeid(func(X,X.size()-1)).name()  << endl;
    // cout << (func(X,X.size()-1)).evaluate()  << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

## Update

After around a year, I am revisiting this problem, and I think I have found a solution; use a pure pure abstract class from which every expression is derived. Then everything (from variables, to the return types of operators, and functions) is a pointer of this abstract class. The code I am currently working on is [here](https://github.com/dkaramit/sadCpp). Notice however that I don't use expression templates for the new design, but I expect to do it at some point in the near future.

Comment: You're using advanced templates, but no smart pointers? :/

Comment: Well... Learning about expression templates was higher in my list of things I wanted to learn. Can smart pointers help me here?

Comment: With this specific error probably not, but in general yes.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll have a look at smart pointers, but for the moment I'm loosing my sleep over this problem...

Comment: its a long question with lots of code, but the code is incomplete. Would be better if you could include a complete example that compiles and produces some output (specifically I tripped over `msg`, not sure if there is more)

Comment: also it seems like you are trying to do many steps at once. When you get a segfault without differentiation then adding differentiation wont make it simpler to fix the segfault

Comment: A [mre] that reproduces the initial segfault you get would be a start. I _think_ this is because the `a+b` evaluation returns a temporary, and your `Expression::assign` stores a reference to that temporary.

Comment: Thanks for the input. i didn't put a block of code because it would look ugly. If a github link is acceptable, the code is [here](https://github.com/dkaramit/ExamplesCpp/tree/master/templates/AlgebraExpressionTemplates). Just download AlgebraExpressionTemplates.hpp, example.cpp, and the makefile. You can compile it by running make, and run the example by running ./example.run .

Comment: Also,  I don't think```Expression::assign``` stores a reference to a temporary, it stores an expression (```GenericExpression```). The problem is infinite recursion because in```Expression::evaluate```. I have editted the question with a code that can be compiled and reproduces the problem. Observe that every time ```evaluate``` is called, ```msg``` prints the typeid of the object owns it. This howyou can be convinced that recursion happens.